# Missing libstdc++.so.5 on CentOS 6.10

Tags: centos, rhel

I need libstdc++.so.5 package. I know that CentOS 6.10 reached EOL and is no longer supported. Is there any repository that still provides packages for CentOS 6.10?

Comment: How would that work? You need matching libc, and probably whatever links libstdc++.so.5 will depend on more than that being there in the right version. You cannot just drop in executables using different library versions in a system and hope that'll work.

Comment: In the case of libstdc++, this is doubly complicated, because you need the right CXXABI version. So, really, this sounds like a packaging/portability problem underlying, and trying to port anything to your CentOS if even the vault, which you already asked about, doesn't contain it, will probably simply not work.